# Density Function $Y=X(2-X)$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ has density function $\frac{x}{2}$ for $0<x<2$ and $0$ otherwise. Now I am wondering what the density function of $Y=X(2-X)$ will be.

I tried to compute $P(Y \geq y)=1-P(Y<y)=1-P(Y \leq y) -P(Y=y)$ and then differentiate to obtain $f_{Y}(y)$. But it don't seem to work. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: $$x^2-2x+1 = -y+1$$
$$x = \sqrt{1-y}+1$$
Now you know how to scale the x-axis. Left to do is renormalization.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**:

Set $Z:=X-1$ and find its PDF.

Find the CDF of $Z^{2}$.

Find the CDF of $1-Z^{2}$ and realize that $1-Z^{2}=Y$.

Find the PDF of $Y$.